# TestNG - Weird behavior

Tags: testng, testng.xml

I am little bit confused by this testNG behavior.

Consider this simple testNG suite. Test2 depends on Test1.  The below suite also starts Test2 only after Test1 which is great!

```
<suite name="testng-behvaior" parallel="none">

    <test name="test1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.Test1" />
            <class name="com.test.Test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Above suite works just fine without any issues.

But consider this. As per testNG documentation, all the `<test>` would be assigned to different thread. Since i have only one `<test>`, only one thread is executing this suite which is fine. But it starts with Test2 before Test1.

```
   <suite name="testng-behvaior" parallel="tests">

        <test name="test1">
            <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
            <classes>
                <class name="com.test.Test1" />
                <class name="com.test.Test2" />
            </classes>
        </test>

    </suite>
```

For me - in the above cases, `parallel="tests"` and `parallel="none"` should not make any difference and behave same.

What makes testNG should behave differently? How can i have the thread to execute the `<classes>` within the `<test>` in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an attribute called `preserve-order`. By default this attribute has a value of `true` at both the `<test>` level and at the `<suite>` level.

This attribute when enabled, causes TestNG to load classes in the same order as defined in the `<test>` tag and then run all the `@Test` methods defined within each of them.

But for this attribute to work, you would need to disable parallelism i.e., you need to set the attribute `parallel` to `none`.

Only then does TestNG execute the tests in the order in which they are found in the `<test>` tag.

So `parallel="tests"` is **NOT EQUAL TO** `parallel="none"`

Comment: So you basically mean this is how testng behaves which could be as designed for you guys but this is wrong!

Comment: TestNG does not care if you had only 1 `<test>` tag or if you had many `<test>` tags. The moment you choose your parallelism strategy via `parallel` attribute the  `preserve-order` functionality is disabled. And lets say you aren't happy with the behavior (which is what it looks like from your response), you should be logging a bug in the TestNG github issues page and debate/discuss it there. My answer was just to clarify to you why are you seeing the behavior, not to justify why it is so. Hope that adds clarity.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes. This ensures that the `<test>` doesn't inherit the parallel attributes from the `<suite>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For those who has been facing similar issue - if you want the tests to be parallel and but want to execute the classes within the test in the sequence, use the below approach

```
   <suite name="testng-behvaior" parallel="tests">

        <test name="test1" parallel="none"> <!-- we do not want parallel here -->
            <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
            <classes>
                <class name="com.test.Test1" />
                <class name="com.test.Test2" />
            </classes>
        </test>

    </suite>
```